# nonlinear regression two equivalent models on paper, but different estimated parameters

Tags: r, regression, nonlinear-regression

I measured one response variable

```
Y1
```

as a function of two measured independent variables

```
X1 and X2
```

It is common practice in my field of research to transform Y1 into another response variable:

```
Y2 = 10*X1 * ((-1)+1 / Y1)
```

Then to fit the following model (M1):

```
Y2 ~ a * X1^b * X2^c + error
```

in order to estimate (a, b, c).

However, it is also possible to estimate these three parameters witout transforming Y1 into Y2, using this equivalent model (M2) (equivalent on paper at least):

```
Y1 ~ 10*X1 / (a * X1^b * X2^c + 10*X1) + error
```

The problem is, these two ways of estimating (a, b, c) yields different estimates. I personnally believe M2 is to be preffered over M1, because calculating Y2 from Y1 and X1 introduces uncertainties from X1 into the nonlinear response variable.

I wish / need to know which model (M1 or M2) to use, and why.

Thanks in advance.

PS: I did not present any reproducible example nor graphs because I think this question is sufficiently general and clear, and does not need it. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: It'd probably help to write out the models properly *with error terms*.

Comment: Sorry I'll add error terms.

Comment: Now I understand the relevance of the very first comment.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Model 2** is

$$Y_1 = \frac{10 X_1}{a X_1^b X_2^c + 10X_1} + \delta$$

whereas **Model 1** is

$$10X_1 \left(-1 + \frac{1}{Y_1}\right) = a X_1^b X_2^c + \varepsilon,$$

which can be solved for $Y_1$ to read

$$Y_1 = \frac{10 X_1}{a X_1^b X_2^c + 10X_1 + \varepsilon}.$$

Implicitly it is supposed the errors $\varepsilon$ or $\delta$, as the case may be, are independent, have identical distributions, and are centered at zero.

**To compare the two models** let's assume the variability of $\varepsilon$ is substantially less than the magnitude of $aX_1^bX_2^c + 10X_1$.  We may then use the Binomial Theorem (or, equivalently, a Taylor series) to approximate the right hand side of Model 1 (to first order in $\varepsilon$) as

$$Y_1 \approx \frac{10 X_1}{a X_1^b X_2^c + 10X_1}\left(1 - \frac{\varepsilon}{a X_1^b X_2^c + 10X_1} + \cdots\right).$$

Comparing to Model 2, we see the difference between them lies in the error terms:

$$\delta \approx \frac{-10 X_1}{\left(a X_1^b X_2^c + 10X_1\right)^2} \varepsilon.$$

**These are different models** because if the $\varepsilon$ have identical distributions, the $\delta$ cannot--since they rescale the $\varepsilon$ by factors that depend on the variables $X_1$ and $X_2$. Conversely, if the $\delta$ have identical distributions then the $\varepsilon$ cannot.

**To decide which one to use** (if either), you will need additional information concerning the distributions of the errors.  This can be obtained in many ways, including

- Theoretical considerations.  For instance, if the error is intended to represent measurement variability of $Y_1$ and that variability is known to be (roughly) constant across a range of values of $Y_1$, the Model 2 is a good choice.
- Analysis of repeated measurements.
- Review of diagnostic information from each model (related to the possible *heteroscedasticity* of the residuals).

---

[image: Figure]

*The red curves show the correct underlying relationships.  The dots show simulated data.  Their vertical deviations from the red curves represent the errors. The dispersion of the errors in Model 1, at the left, visibly varies with the independent variables. The dispersion in Model 2, at the right, does not.*

This figure shows data simulated with the `R` code below.  To simplify the presentation, all values of $X_2$ were set to a constant value, causing all variation in $Y_1$ to be associated with variation in $X_1$ only.  This simplification does not change the nature of the differences between the two models.

```R
a <- 1
b <- 2
c <- 3
n <- 250
sigma <- 2
#
# Generate data according to two models.
#
set.seed(17)
x1 <- rgamma(n, 2) + 1
x2 <- rep(1, n)
epsilon <- rnorm(n, sd=sigma)
y.m1 <- 10 * x1 / (a * x1^b * x2^c + 10*x1 + epsilon)

# (Make them have comparable errors on average.)
tau <- mean(abs(-10 * x1 / (a * x1^b * x2^c + 10*x1)^2))
delta <- rnorm(n, sd=tau)
y.m2 <- 10 * x1 / (a * x1^b * x2^c + 10*x1) + delta
#
# Plot the simulated data.
#
reference <- function() curve(10 * x / (a*x^b + 10*x), add=TRUE, col="Red", lwd=2)
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(x1, y.m1, main="Model 1", xlab="X1", ylab="Y1", col="#00000070")
reference()
plot(x1, y.m2, main="Model 2", xlab="X1", ylab="Y1", col="#00000070")
reference()
```

Comment: This is really just an elaboration of @Scortchi's comment on the question.

Comment: Thank you very much ! I would not have been able to elaborate on @Scortchi's comment, but now I understand it and why it was so relevant. Now, I know WHY I must choose one model (because these two models are fondamentally different from each others), and HOW to choose the right model for my datas. If I understand you well, residuals estimated by one of the two models will be normally distributed, while residuals estimated from the other model will not. And I should choose the model with normally distributed residuals.

Comment: You're almost correct. We have no basis to suppose the errors will have Normal distributions, and in practice this is rare. The models that are simplest to interpret and mathematically most tractable tend to be those with nearly *symmetrical* distributions of residuals that have nearly identical shapes and dispersions across all values of the independent variables. Although there is no guarantee, often it is the case that a model with one of these characteristics (symmetry or homoscedasticity) also has the other one, at least to a practical approximation.

Answer (score 5):

There are NOT equivalent least squares models. The error in one model is a transformation of the error in the other. Whichever model's error is closer to being Normally distributed should be the better model.  Edit: see whuber's answer for more elaboration on the error transformation.

There is a second matter as well, and that is the question of what numerical solution is obtained by the nonlinear least solution algorithm. The solution obtained can depends on the algorithm used to solve it as well as the starting value (initial guess) for the parameters being estimated. Depending on the algorithm and starting value, it's possible that the algorithm will exit without finding a local optimum. It's possible that a local optimum will be found which is not the global optimum.

You should want the globally optimal solution.  Whether you find it is another matter.  That's where it helps to know what you're doing in nonlinear optimization, which unfortunately most people performing nonlinear least squares don't.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I understand now these models are not equivalent, although I do not quite so well understand what does it mean for an error term to be the reciprocal of another one. However, you give me a way to choose between these two models (the one whose residuals are closer to being normally distributed). However, if I know how to test residuals for normality, I don't know, currently, how to compare two sets of residuals and choose the most normal one. Any advice, keyword, is welcome.

Comment: About the second part of your answer, I have reasonable certitude that both model's estimated parameters are their respective global optimum.

Comment: I edited out my statement about the errors being reciprocal - see whuber's answer for more info on that. Regarding normality of errors, see whuiber's answer, go back to first principles on the model if possible, and also do this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_probability_plot .

Comment: What is the basis for your reasonable certitude that both model's estimated parameters are their respective global optimum?  What software/algorithm did you use to find the optimum? Did you use a "rigorous" global optimizer (not for instance the cr@p in the MATLAB global optimization toolbox), or at least a semi-rigorous global optimizer such as BARON?  Did you use multiple starting values?  Did you use the solution from one model as a starting value to solve the other model?

Comment: I use R's nlsLM function from minpack.lm package for nonlinear parameter estimation using Levenberg-Marquardt fitting algorithm because it is said to be more robust against bad starting values. Also because the starting values are common estimated values from previous experiments, and finally because L-M algorithm gives equal estimates to default Gauss-Newton algorithm from the more conventional nls function in stats package.

Comment: The convergence criteria http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/minpack.lm/minpack.lm.pdf look unreliable. Nevertheless, it's quite possible the algorithm converged to a local optimum. The fact that you got the same solution with different but closely related algorithms, as well as using starting values from previous experiments, should NOT provide any confidence you are finding the global optimum, as opposed to a local optimum. Also note that LM and Gauss-Newton both make the same approximation to the Hessian which is valid only if the residuals at the (local) optimum are sufficiently small.

Comment: The previous experiments may have all found the same local, but not globally optimal solution.  So when you provide similar data and start in the same region, you may get basically the same local optimum which is not  the global optimum.  I am not saying however that you did not find the global optimum - just that you shouldn't have "reasonable certitude" based on the reasons you provided.

Comment: The greater robustness of Levenberg-Marquardt (L-M) vs. Gauss-Newton (G-N) pertains to finding a local minimum. There really is not an improved robustness to finding a global minimum, other than that at least L-M has a better chance of finding a local minimum, which may turn out to be a global minimum. than G-N. They both make the same approximation to the Hessian, based on J'*J, where J is the Jacobian, for a model in the form 1/2* (sum squared residuals). If you this in BARON http://www.minlp.com/ , you can be reasonably assured of getting a global minimum if it claims to have found it.

Comment: If you don''t use a global optimizer such as BARON, your best prospects are if you use a trust region Newton's algorithm, such as in KNITRO http://www.ziena.com/knitro.htm with hessopt 1 (not the nonlinear least squares routines under MATLAB using L-M or G-N). Even then, you need to use multiple starting values, and there is no guarantee you will find the global optimum. The most robust algorithms for nonlinear least squares (which I referenced above) are not specialized to nonlinear least squares, rather, they are general purpose nonlinear optimizers.